VBAのエラー処理について教えてください
修正が必要なコードがあり、確認中なのですがほぼ全ての行にエラー処理が入っております。
自分はプログラマではないのでよくわからないのですが、以下のようにクリティカル？な処理には全て If Not .. GoTo ErrProc が入っているのですが、クリティカルな処理はこのように記載するほうがよいのでしょうか？
それともエラー処理自体を関数化するなど別の方法があったりするのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。
Sub main()
'DBへ接続
If Not DB接続処理(PATH) Then
    MsgBox "エラー"
    GoTo ErrProc
End If

'SQL実行
If Not executeSQL(strSQL) Then
    MsgBox "エラー"
    GoTo ErrProc
end if 

'関数
If Not getStr(myStr) Then
            GoTo ErrProc
End If

'─────────────────────────
EndProc:
    Exit Sub
ErrProc:
    GoTo EndProc
End Sub


コードはこれですべてでしょうか？ Goto ErrProc で指定されたジャンプ先が定義されていたりしませんか？ 参考: On Errorステートメント | ExcelVBA入門

コードを追記しました。ErrProcの後はEndProcに飛んでExit Subするようになっております

現在のコードで何か問題があるのでしょうか？DB接続時などの予期せぬエラーへの対策だと思いますが。特段問題がなければ今動いているコードをいじることはしない方が良いかと思います。

この辺の記事が参考になるかも。上級者を目指すExcelVBA #1 『エラー処理』とそれから始まる12件の記事, エラーに負けない それから150ページもある個人出版らしき本 ExcelVBAで使えるチェック機能コード集の基礎、処理開始編

ありがとうございます。参考になります！

プログラム実行時になにか問題があった場合、「どこでエラーが起きて」「何が原因だったか」をプログラムもしくは実行環境が常に親切に教えてくれるとは限りません。
ですので、エラーが起こりそうな箇所にあらかじめ if 文等でプログラムの作者が備えておく…というのは、シンプルだけどよく使われる手法の一つです。
一方で、質問のコードではせっかくエラーハンドリングをしているのに、どの処理でも単に "エラー" という短いメッセージを表示しているのみなので、原因箇所の絞り込みができないという点で有用では無さそうです。


クリティカルな処理はこのように記載するほうがよいのでしょうか？

常にこのような記載がよいとは言い切れません。
特にプログラム規模が大きいとき、毎回エラーチェックをするのは冗長で、手間となり、
タイプミスの原因になる場合があります。

それともエラー処理自体を関数化するなど別の方法があったりするのでしょうか？

他のプログラム言語と同様に、VBAにも例外処理があります。
エラー処理を一か所にまとめて記述できる点、
エラー(例外)が発生した箇所で停止させデバッグ可能な状態で実行できる点、
などのメリットがあります。

Public Sub TestFunc(ByRef flag As Boolean)
    If flag Then
        Debug.Print ("True")
    Else
        Debug.Print ("Fale")
        Call Err.Raise(1 + vbObjectError + 512, "TestFunc", "プログラムエラー" & " flag:[" & flag & "]")
    End If
    
End Sub

Public Sub main()
    On Error GoTo ErrorProc
    
    Debug.Print ("--- Start")
'    Call TestFunc(True)
    Call TestFunc(False)
    Debug.Print ("--- End")
    Exit Sub
ErrorProc:
    Call MsgBox(Err.Description)
    Debug.Print ("--- End(error)")

End Sub


